# Excel Linked Pictures performance fix: worksheet.pictures throws type mismatch error 13 in For Each loop -SOLVED-

Tags: excel, vba

I try to develop a VBA routine that allows me to manage the performance issue as well as some nice features that come with the use of linked pictures / camera tool.

The code hereunder iterates through the .pictures collection of the worksheet, so I can extract the formula from the pic.formula member and use it later.

My problem: The code works in test workbooks, but not the target one. As soon as the code hits the line For each pic in worksheet.pictures I get the runtime error 13, type mismatch

I tried to work with shapes which does not throw the error, but when I do so I cannot access the .formula member of the shape object. Error 438, property not supported by the object.

I tried to cast a shape to picture using the shape.type property to detect a picture. Didn't work.

I tried to figure out if there is a 255 char limit problem with the .pictures collection by inspecting all picture names as well as constructing a sheet with 300+ linked pictures, linked pictures with linked pictures in them and also various groupings. In the test workbook it worked perfectly, in the target workbook i get the error.

I tried the code on clean sheets in the affected workbook, the error is thrown there as well.

I work the latest Office 365 release and Windows 10.

The code herunder works fine if you create a workbook and place some linked pictures (camera tool) on the sheet.

Any suggestions what I should try next?

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim pic As Picture
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim ListAll As String
    Dim arr() As Variant

    i = 1 'for my array
    Set sht = Sheets("Sheet1")

   For Each pic In sht.Pictures
       ReDim Preserve arr(1 To i)
       arr(i) = pic.Name & " " & pic.Formula
       i = i + 1
   Next pic

'control output
   ListAll = ""

   While i > 1
     i = i - 1
     ListAll = ListAll & i & ":" & arr(i) & " "
   Wend

   MsgBox ListAll

End Sub
```

The output should be a message box with a list of the pictures and according links/formula's

What I get is the Type Mismatch error 13.

UPDATE:

I altered the code, works in the first broken workbook. I use the Shapes collection to scroll through the shapes, filter out the pictures, and initialize the pic variable from there.
I was able to narrow the problem down, but I have no conclusive RCA. My guess is that the unexpected behavior is related to the use of scrollbars (i let the user manipulate cells through scrollbars); 
The mismatch error occurs when the first scrollbar gets 'hit' in the 'for each pic in worksheet.pictures' loop. But I could not reproduce the error consistently in test workbooks.

Still no clue why, but here is a workaround that does the trick:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim shp As Shape
    Dim pic As Picture
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim ListAll As String
    Dim arr() As Variant

    i = 1 'for my array
    Set sht = Sheets("Sheet1")

    For Each shp In sht.Shapes

     If shp.Type = msoPicture Then

         Set pic = sht.Pictures(shp.Name)

         ReDim Preserve arr(1 To i)
         arr(i) = pic.Name & " " & pic.Formula
         i = i + 1

     End If

   Next shp

'control output
   ListAll = ""

   While i > 1
     i = i - 1
     ListAll = ListAll & i & ":" & arr(i) & " "
   Wend

   MsgBox ListAll

End Sub
```

Comment: The error raises on this statement?? `For Each pic In sht.Pictures`?

Comment: Yes, exactly. that is where the error occurs.

Comment: Hmmm. That doesn't make any sense. `sht.Pictures` is a collection of `Picture` objects. I can't see any reason why that line would fail. Even if there are no picture on the sheet, that will just be an empty iterable.

Comment: Yes, i am really stuck here. When I construct sheets from scratch or I put it into random workbooks the code works. Only in the target book it fails. I will paste the code in earlier versions and try to determine when the code breaks.

Comment: Are you getting a type mismatch on the first iteration, or you get a bunch and suddenly it chokes on one particular picture?

Comment: Try late binding  - declare `pic As Variant`, then insert `Debug.Assert TypeOf pic Is Excel.Picture` before the `ReDim`. Does the assert fail at any point?

Comment: Hi Matthieu, It starts at the very first iteration. I will look at your approach, one sec

Comment: I found the last iteration that worked and the first that is broken...The first broken version has copied sheets in it from another excel version. Maybe that is causing the trouble.

Comment: Matthieu, the debug.assert fails when I try to access the pic.formula with error 438. Just as it would with Dim pic as Shape

Comment: I could isolate the sheet and version where the error 13 gets thrown. It is a sheet with two scroll bars linked to a cell. It is available in both versions, the one that does throw the error, and the one that does not.
When I delete BOTH of the scroll bars in the workbook that has the error, then the code works, no error thrown. Now I'll figure out if there is a difference between the scroll bars in Book/Sheet A and B...This is an unexpected one...

Comment: Ok I'm tired now. Inspecting the document with OpenXML. Something seems to be corrupt. I'll post it as soon as I have found the problem. Thank you for helping out David and Matthieu